# Как получить измененные данные в textarea?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть блок textarea в который при загрузке страницы помещают текст

```js
$('#Text').html('sometext');

console.log($('#Text').html());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="Text"></textarea>
```

После изменения содержимого в браузере, я пытаюсь обработать новую информацию. Но при вызове $('#Text').html() получаю старые данные. Как получить новые?

Comment: Не воспроизводится. Локализуйте баг

Comment: @Арсен могу ли я использовать событие change если изменения нужно отправлять на сервер? Я собираюсь использовать Ajax и думаю отправка каждого символа плохая идея.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ещё один вариант. Отправляет данные в момент ввода.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
 $('#Text').html('sometext');

  $('#Text').on('input', function () {
  console.log($(this).val());

 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="Text"></textarea>
```